# Play Framework cannot find QueryStringBinders

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3, querystringparameter

I have a case class in the model package called *CoordinatesTranslationDTO*:

```scala
case class CoordinatesTranslationDTO(locale: String, lat: BigDecimal, lng: BigDecimal)
```

I'm importing this in the QueryStringBinders controller like so:

```scala
import models.CoordinatesTranslationDTO
```

My implementation of the object in the QueryStringBinders controller looks like this:

```scala
object QueryStringBinders {
  implicit def coordinatesTranslationStringBinder(
                                                   implicit bigDecimalBinder: QueryStringBindable[BigDecimal],
                                                   stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]
                                                 ): QueryStringBindable[CoordinatesTranslationDTO] =
    new QueryStringBindable[CoordinatesTranslationDTO] {
      private def subBind[T](key: String, subkey: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]])
                            (implicit b: QueryStringBindable[T]): Either.RightProjection[String, Option[T]] = {
        b.bind(s"$key.$subkey", params).map(_.right.map(r => Option(r))).getOrElse(Right(None)).right
      }

      override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, CoordinatesTranslationDTO]] = Some {
        def bnd[T](s: String)(implicit b: QueryStringBindable[T]) = subBind[T](key, s, params)

        for {
          locale <- bnd[String]("locale")
          lat <- bnd[BigDecimal]("lat")
          lng <- bnd[BigDecimal]("lng")
        } yield CoordinatesTranslationDTO(locale, lat, lng)
      }

      override def unbind(key: String, coordinates: CoordinatesTranslationDTO): String = {
        def ubnd[T](key: String, s: Option[T])(implicit b: QueryStringBindable[T]) = s.map(f => b.unbind(key, f))

        val keys = Seq(
          ubnd("lat", coordinates.lat),
          ubnd("lng", coordinates.lng),
          ubnd("locale", coordinates.locale)
        ).flatten
        keys.mkString("&")
      }
    }
}
```

And my route in the routes file looks like this:

```scala
GET           /people/translation                                                          controllers.PeopleController.getOrCreatePersonLocation(p: models.CoordinatesTranslationDTO)
```

I already run `sbt clean`, set `cleanFiles` and God knows how many commands more. But nothing seems to work. All I get is:

```sh
[error] /Users/developmentuser/Desktop/Jobs/parent/solar/conf/routes:269:1: No QueryString binder found for type models.CoordinatesTranslationDTO. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is actually that Play can't find an implicit `QueryStringBindable[BigDecimal]`, which is required for your `coordinatesTranslationStringBinder`.

The error message is misleading. It is generated by the following code in Play, which cannot distinguish between either i) `QueryStringBindable[A]` not being implemented at all, or ii) there is an implementation of `QueryStringBindable[A]` but its implicit requirements cannot be met:

```
  // mvc/Binders.scala
@implicitNotFound(
  "No QueryString binder found for type ${A}. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type."
)
trait QueryStringBindable[A] {
```

I had the same problem and had to figure out what was going on by reading the source closely then narrow it down by calling for each of my implicitly provided sub-binders one by one until I found the culprit. Too much magic!

(You can implement a binder for `BigDecimal` using the `Parsing` helper class from `mvc/Binders.scala`.)

I can't see how Play can easily fix this error message. Perhaps they could just add "(or its implicit dependencies cannot be resolved)" to this message.

Comment: Hey, I no longer work with that company , but yes. I forgot to update, that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At least one thing that you forgot is at add parameter in your routes file. The `:p` param in your route. It should be same as one that you pass to your `getOrCreatePersonLocation` function.

```
GET   /people/translation/:p   controllers.PeopleController.getOrCreatePersonLocation(p: models.CoordinatesTranslationDTO)
```

Comment: Thanks Yevgen but there's no need for it since is a QueryStringBindable not a PathBindable. The format for receiving parameters would be: 

`/people/translation?p.locale=en&p.lat=42.23123&p.lng=75.2123`